# php pages always redirect to the login page even when logged in

Tags: php, redirect, authentication

I have created a login page that authenticate the user and direct the user to the admin page once logged in, however the other pages should have the following code at the top in order to only enable logged users to access:

```
<?php require_once("../includes/db_connection.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("../includes/functions.php"); ?>
<?php confirm_logged_in(); ?>
```

where the function confirm_logged_in() looks like:

```
function logged_in() {
return isset($_SESSION['admin_id']);
}

function confirm_logged_in() {
if (!logged_in()) {
redirect_to("login.php");
}}
```

Now my problem is that when I add the first snippet of code to the other pages it keeps me redirected to the login page and I don't know what I'm missing.

Comment: Well.. probably `$_SESSION['admin_id']` is null.

Comment: You will have to provide more code than tht... the login

Comment: What is in your $_SESSION array? Have you confirmed that 'admin_id' is infact set and has a value?

Comment: session_start();
 
 function message() {
  if (isset($_SESSION["message"])) {
   $output = "<div class=\"message\">";
   $output .= htmlentities($_SESSION["message"]);
   $output .= "</div>";
   
   // clear message after use
   $_SESSION["message"] = null;
   
   return $output;
  }
 }